# node.js doesn't work i think it maybe problem of install or i don't know

Tags: node.js

[it doesn't show the result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6Mr6.png)

[also in cmd.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvJjO.png)

I tried to install 'node.js' again.
And the route of a file is correct.

I don't know why it doesn't act.

Comment: just run `node` in cmd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your hello.js is at the same location as that of you node ? if not then try running node 'path of your hello.js/fileName'

Comment: it now work suddenly.... it maybe a labtop's problem... sorry

Answer (score 1):

On your first picture the file is not saved.